# mask não é uma função

Tags: jquery, mask-plugin

estou com erro em uma função mask do jQuery.

Eis meu código:

```
//############## MASK INPUT    
$(".formDate").mask("99/99/9999");
$(".formTime").mask("99/99/9999 99:99");
$(".formCep").mask("99999-999");
$(".formCpf").mask("999.999.999-99");

$('.formPhone').focusout(function () {
    var phone, element;
    element = $(this);
    element.unmask();
    phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (phone.length > 10) {
        element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
    } else {
        element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    }
}).trigger('focusout');
```

O erro retornado pelo console é:

```
TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function
```

A documentação do erro:
[documentação do erro](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)

o include do js:

```
<script src="<?= BASE; ?>/_cdn/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?= BASE; ?>/_cdn/maskinput.js"></script>
```

o conteúdo do maskinput.js

```
  /*
    Masked Input plugin for jQuery
    Copyright (c) 2007-2013 Josh Bush (digitalbush.com)
    Licensed under the MIT license (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)
    Version: 1.3.1
*/
(function(e){function t(){var e=document.createElement("input"),t="onpaste";return e.setAttribute(t,""),"function"==typeof e[t]?"paste":"input"}var n,a=t()+".mask",r=navigator.userAgent,i=/iphone/i.test(r),o=/android/i.test(r);e.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},dataName:"rawMaskFn",placeholder:"_"},e.fn.extend({caret:function(e,t){var n;if(0!==this.length&&!this.is(":hidden"))return"number"==typeof e?(t="number"==typeof t?t:e,this.each(function(){this.setSelectionRange?this.setSelectionRange(e,t):this.createTextRange&&(n=this.createTextRange(),n.collapse(!0),n.moveEnd("character",t),n.moveStart("character",e),n.select())})):(this[0].setSelectionRange?(e=this[0].selectionStart,t=this[0].selectionEnd):document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&(n=document.selection.createRange(),e=0-n.duplicate().moveStart("character",-1e5),t=e+n.text.length),{begin:e,end:t})},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(t,r){var c,l,s,u,f,h;return!t&&this.length>0?(c=e(this[0]),c.data(e.mask.dataName)()):(r=e.extend({placeholder:e.mask.placeholder,completed:null},r),l=e.mask.definitions,s=[],u=h=t.length,f=null,e.each(t.split(""),function(e,t){"?"==t?(h--,u=e):l[t]?(s.push(RegExp(l[t])),null===f&&(f=s.length-1)):s.push(null)}),this.trigger("unmask").each(function(){function c(e){for(;h>++e&&!s[e];);return e}function d(e){for(;--e>=0&&!s[e];);return e}function m(e,t){var n,a;if(!(0>e)){for(n=e,a=c(t);h>n;n++)if(s[n]){if(!(h>a&&s[n].test(R[a])))break;R[n]=R[a],R[a]=r.placeholder,a=c(a)}b(),x.caret(Math.max(f,e))}}function p(e){var t,n,a,i;for(t=e,n=r.placeholder;h>t;t++)if(s[t]){if(a=c(t),i=R[t],R[t]=n,!(h>a&&s[a].test(i)))break;n=i}}function g(e){var t,n,a,r=e.which;8===r||46===r||i&&127===r?(t=x.caret(),n=t.begin,a=t.end,0===a-n&&(n=46!==r?d(n):a=c(n-1),a=46===r?c(a):a),k(n,a),m(n,a-1),e.preventDefault()):27==r&&(x.val(S),x.caret(0,y()),e.preventDefault())}function v(t){var n,a,i,l=t.which,u=x.caret();t.ctrlKey||t.altKey||t.metaKey||32>l||l&&(0!==u.end-u.begin&&(k(u.begin,u.end),m(u.begin,u.end-1)),n=c(u.begin-1),h>n&&(a=String.fromCharCode(l),s[n].test(a)&&(p(n),R[n]=a,b(),i=c(n),o?setTimeout(e.proxy(e.fn.caret,x,i),0):x.caret(i),r.completed&&i>=h&&r.completed.call(x))),t.preventDefault())}function k(e,t){var n;for(n=e;t>n&&h>n;n++)s[n]&&(R[n]=r.placeholder)}function b(){x.val(R.join(""))}function y(e){var t,n,a=x.val(),i=-1;for(t=0,pos=0;h>t;t++)if(s[t]){for(R[t]=r.placeholder;pos++<a.length;)if(n=a.charAt(pos-1),s[t].test(n)){R[t]=n,i=t;break}if(pos>a.length)break}else R[t]===a.charAt(pos)&&t!==u&&(pos++,i=t);return e?b():u>i+1?(x.val(""),k(0,h)):(b(),x.val(x.val().substring(0,i+1))),u?t:f}var x=e(this),R=e.map(t.split(""),function(e){return"?"!=e?l[e]?r.placeholder:e:void 0}),S=x.val();x.data(e.mask.dataName,function(){return e.map(R,function(e,t){return s[t]&&e!=r.placeholder?e:null}).join("")}),x.attr("readonly")||x.one("unmask",function(){x.unbind(".mask").removeData(e.mask.dataName)}).bind("focus.mask",function(){clearTimeout(n);var e;S=x.val(),e=y(),n=setTimeout(function(){b(),e==t.length?x.caret(0,e):x.caret(e)},10)}).bind("blur.mask",function(){y(),x.val()!=S&&x.change()}).bind("keydown.mask",g).bind("keypress.mask",v).bind(a,function(){setTimeout(function(){var e=y(!0);x.caret(e),r.completed&&e==x.val().length&&r.completed.call(x)},0)}),y()}))}})})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Adicionou o Javascript da máscara no seu projeto?

Comment: Importou o jquery?

Comment: sim, estou usando o jQuery mais atual, versão 3

Comment: Verificou se o plugin é compativel com essa versão? edite a pergunte e adicione os 'imports' dos arquivos javascript.

Comment: editei e adicionei o conteúdo do arquivo

Comment: não consigo encontrar essa documentação no jquery, pelo menos no deprecated não encontrei nada

Comment: acabei de ver no site do plugin, ele é compatível somente com a versão jQuery 1.9

Alguém conhece algum plugin de máscara que seja compatível do jQuery 3?

Comment: Ja tentou esse aqui https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Comment: estava tentando ele, mas estou achando muito difícil... mas valeu pela dica

Comment: @Jardel, na verdade é muito simples. Veja esses exemplos que criei pra você (com jQuery 3): https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/u8v1aLeb/

Comment: Dá uma olhada no repositório da jquery: https://plugins.jquery.com/?s=mask

Answer (score -1):

Fiz algo parecido estes dias. Criei um **input** para o telefone e criei esse código para o id:

```
    $(function(){
        $("#txtTelefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
        $("#txtTelefone").blur(function(event) {
            if($(this).val().length == 15){
                $('#txtTelefone').mask('(99) 99999-999?9');
            } else {
                $('#txtTelefone').mask('(99) 9999-9999?9');
            }
        });
    });
```

O plugin utilizado foi o https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Testei no meu projeto e funcionou com https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js